# Pyhon screen shot webpage without Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

Is there a way to take screenshot of page without a web driver? I mean, all i want is to take screenshot in the backround , without opened window.

Comment: Maybe try https://www.browserstack.com/?

Comment: Have you tried the html2image library? https://pypi.org/project/html2image/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with headless option. Refer the site for more info https://medium.com/@dschnr/using-headless-chrome-as-an-automated-screenshot-tool-4b07dffba79a

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean, do you mean just a normal screenshot or a screenshot from google?